# iTextSharp: Display "Open/Save" dialog box when PDF file is created

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, save-as

I am using iTextSharp to create a PDF file (I use C#). The file is created fine; however, it is saved in a folder. The file is created in response to a link button click and I want to display the Open/Save dialog box rather than save the fie in a folder.
I use the following:

```
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    Document doc1 = new Document();
    PdfWriter pdfw = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc1, ms);
    doc1.open();
    string sPath = Server.MapPath("PDF/");
    string sFileName = "Something.PDF";

    // create the PDF content

    doc1.Close();
    byte[] content = ms.ToArray();
    using (FileStream fs = FileStream.Create(sPath + sFileName))
    {
        fs.Write(content, 0, (int)content.Length);
    }
}
```

Am I doing this wrong? It creates the file and saves it in "blahblah/PDF" folder but does not display Open/Save dialog bx.

Comment: You didn't tag this ASP.Net so are you working in a desktop app?

Comment: This is a web application (.Net 3.5, C# 2.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the file, use `Response.TransmitFile` method to flush it in the user's browser.

```
Response.Clear(); 
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=buylist.pdf");
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/myfile.pdf"));
```

Comment: Thanks Vahid. Is there any way to do this without saving the file to a folder first? I wonder what happens if 100 users click on the link to create the PDF file at the same time, using different criteria to generate the data.

Comment: Instead of `Response.TransmitFile()` you can use `Response.BinaryWrite()` and pass your byte array directly to that.

Comment: Excellent! That solved it. It displays Open/Save without requiring to write the file to a folder first. Vahid's suggestion pointed me in the right direction and you change finalized it.